# C++: error LNK1104 File ...lib could not be opened although it exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, include, libraries

Can somebody tell me what he would first check if he gets the following error?

```
error LNK1104 File "M:/SDKS/DXSDK/samples/C++/DirectShow/BaseClasses/Debug/strmbasd.lib" could not be opened
```

My project is a COM component.

In the project settings I have the following:

Reference directories: 
M:\SDKs\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\BaseClasses
DKs\Windows\v6.0\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\BaseClasses\

The file "streambasd.lib" is located in "M:\SDKs\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\BaseClasses\Debug"

Did I do anything obvious wrong?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: It says that it could not be *opened*, not that it cannot be *found*.  The file is (probably) either locked or read only.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the library under Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.

Comment: I didt. I even copied the path and pasted it into the explorer. Windows asked me which application I want to open "strmbasd.lib" with, so I guess I did it correctly.